# Xcode: Change Bundle Identifier Case with automatically managed signing

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 8 seems to have the convention that the bundle identifier follows the case of the app name e.g. com.test.AppName. However in our team it is convention to have it all lowercase. After we created a new project we tried to change the case of the bundle id but with no success. What we tried:

**1) Tried to change it in Xcode**
We changed it to lowercase and then changed some capabilities. The result was the error:

`The app ID "com.xyz.xyz" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.`

**2) Delete in the developer account**
There seems no possibility to delete an automatically generated bundle ID online.

Is there any way to fix this?